# What is the disadvantage of using a boost converter?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator

I am referring to  [this boost converter.](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf)

I want to know the disadvantage of this. It isn't possible that this could just generate free voltage, there would be some disadvantage. I actually need this to power some servo motors because I have a supply of 2 volts and want to multiply it to about 5-6 volts, and control using an Arduino. Is it possible, or is it too good to be true?

EDIT: [This is the full PCB.](https://robu.in/product/xl6009-dc-dc-step-up-converter-performance-ultra-lm2577-booster-circuit-board/)

Comment: Free voltage does not mean free energy.

Comment: Yes, thats what i want to understand, what will the drawbacks be?

Comment: There's [voltage multipliers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier) and then there's [boost converters.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter)  The two are very different.

Comment: "I have a supply of 2 volts" The datasheet gives the minimum operating voltage of this ic as 5 V so you'll need to change the supply or your smps ic.

Comment: What is the 2V supply? What kind of servos are you planning on driving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A boost converter can increase the output voltage however this is at the cost of needing more supply current. Ignoring losses Vin x Iin = Vout x Iout. So if you where say increasing 5V to 10V your input current would have to be twice your output current.

This means that power in = power out so you are not getting free energy.

In practice with a supply of 2V your losses are going to be rather  high and this will require careful selection of the boost converter.

Comment: Converters are not perfectly efficient, so power out < power in.

Comment: @John Doty note "ignoring losses".

Comment: Oh, so the wattage will remain the same , i.e., V*I ?

Comment: Also, will this be applicable vice-versa, stepping down the voltage?

Comment: Correct for both questions.

Answer (score 5):

For a voltage multiplier, the output voltage depends on the input voltage and losses.$$V_{out}=K{ }V_{in}-V_{\text{losses}}$$ For a boost converter, the output voltage is independent from the input voltage. $$V_{out}=KV_{\text{ref}}$$

> there would be some disadvantage

The disadvantage of a voltage multiplier is the internal losses reduce the output voltage. Mostly because it is an open loop system, so the load will pull the voltage down.

The input current is greater than the output current.$$I_{in}=I_{out}+I_{\text{switching losses}}$$

The advantage of boost converters is that they are closed loop systems. The output voltage is measured and compared to a reference voltage, then adjustments are made to remove the error. This allows the output voltage to not respond to changes input voltage or load current.

As the input voltage drops, the input current increases to maintaining the output voltage and current.$$I_{in}=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}I_{out}+\text{switching losses}$$

Power efficiency is still a concern. For both multipliers and boost converters,$$P_{in}=P_{out}+P_{\text{losses}}$$

Modern boost converters are very efficient achieving 98% in some circumstances. Their closed loop error correcting structure makes them more desirable.

Comment: OP's linked datasheet gives a typical efficiency of 92%.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use something like a DC-DC converter to obtain an appropriate voltage for some element, from a source of inappropriate voltage, but there are power and current considerations, which I'll describe here.

Don't forget that power being delivered to the load is the product of voltage across it *and* current through it, not just the voltage.

Voltage is a measure of the amount of energy that each charge has to deliver to the load on its journey through the load, but you mustn't overlook that current is a measure of how many charges per second actually make that journey! That's why both are important.

Energy is always conserved, (as is power, which is just energy per second), so if more energy is being delivered to the load each second, then more energy must be leaving the source each second.

Power \$P\$ being delivered to a thing, is the product of voltage \$V\$ across the thing, and current \$I\$ through the thing:

$$ P = V \times I $$

When using a DC-DC converter to double voltage, you might have an arrangement like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPaDTJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is "the thing" receiving energy here, and battery V1 is the source of that energy.

The voltage at the output (10V) is double the input voltage (5V). This circuit is taking some power \$P_{IN}\$ from source V1, and delivering all that power to load R1, as \$P_{OUT}\$.

Assuming this DC-DC converter is 100% efficient (which it won't be in real life, it will always consuming some power itself), and remembering the law of conservation of energy, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{IN} &= P_{OUT} \\ \\
V_{IN} \times I_{IN} &= V_{OUT} \times I_{OUT} \\ \\
I_{IN} &= \frac{V_{OUT} \times I_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} \\ \\
&= \frac{10V \times 100mA}{5V} \\ \\
&= 200mA
\end{aligned}
$$

In other words, by doubling output voltage we are also doubling the current required from the input source. I'm sorry to say that there's no free lunch here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers...

All switching power supplies are a concern for EMC. Significant care needs to be taken to avoid your PCB or other components becoming a radio broadcasting at the switching frequency.

Switching power supplies also inherently produce some ripple on the output voltage. This makes them unsuitable for higher-precision analogue circuits on their own. Best practise if you care about noise is normally to follow the switcher with a linear power supply, which drops the voltage further but gives a very much cleaner supply.